# GDB on Visual Studio Code trying to read headers from a non-existent directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gdb, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to debug a program written in c++ using gdb from vscode.

When the debugger calls the function `ifstream()` from the header `fstream`, it's unable to find the header file because gdb is looking for it on the directory `/build/gcc/src/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/` , which doesn't exist and results in wrong code execution.
I've fixed this by using the command `directory /usr/include/c++/10.2.0/` on gdb from the terminal, but this doesn't seem to fix the problem when I use gdb from vscode.

[Error message from vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5jWs.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ***results in wrong code execution*** It may be visualizing the wrong code as you step through the debugger however I expect the correct code is being debugged.

Comment: The directory exists.  On a different machine.  Just doesn't exist on your machine.

Comment: I expect that was the path on the build system that compiled the standard library for whatever linux distro you are using.

Comment: @drescherjm The weirdest part is that there are no errors when I execute the program without the debugger, only when I run it with dbg.

Comment: Maybe your code has some Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have solved this problem.
When gdb is executed, it looks for a configuration file called `.gdbinit` on the user's home directory (Unix systems). To give gdb the right header's directory it's as easy as put the command `source {your header's directory}` on the file previously mentioned.

If Visual Studio doesn't recognice c/c++ functions, just put the header's location on your settings.json file (`"C_Cpp.default.includePath": ["your header's directory"]`.

[Here's more info about gdb init file](https://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/%7Elearn/debugging/modules/gdb_init_file/)